# Ubuntu 15.04 after reboot lost Ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet, reboot, 15.04

I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 and after a reboot I lose my Ethernet connection. After I've disable and re-enabled my connection Ethernet works fine, until I reboot again.
This has been going on ever since my first install of Ubuntu 15.04. Everything worked fine in Ubuntu 14

```
    mrgobus@mrgobus-home:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(ethernet|network)"
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please include proper hardware information in your question. Provide numeric id's like the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(ethernet|network)"` (if PCI device and not USB, and both before and after the reboot working/failing). Also include what you are seeing on your screen; does it report a link that is down or is the network controller not recognized at all anymore? Please be specific and complete, so we can help you better. Remember that we don't have your hardware and we can't see you screen so we rely on the information you provide in your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question for additional details. Comments aren't fit for that. Also, this is not a forum, but a Q&A site where we expect users to put all relevant information in the question body. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some hardware revisions of this Ethernet adapter have issues with kernel driver r8169. In this case a specific driver can be installed, it is in Ubuntu repository. Just run:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Comment: Thank you, I've also linked your answer from this question that seems related http://askubuntu.com/questions/617487/15-04-vivid-vervet-intermittent-selective-network-outages/623887#623887