# 15.04 vivid vervet intermittent selective network outages

Tags: networking, upgrade, ethernet, 15.04

I recently upgraded from 14.10 to 15.04 and immediately after the upgrade was finished, I began having network problems. At first I thought the errors were related to my squid3 cache, but I have ruled that out as now it is affecting my email as well.

What happens is that sometimes, when I am browsing the web or otherwise using the network (IPv4 only, IPv6 turned off, wired Ethernet connected to a LinkSys WiFi router connected to a cable modem), the system complains that it cannot find DNS info, or cannot connect to, a particular host. This is a very selective outage, because the rest of my connections will be fine in the meantime, and it is only temporary, because if I try again in a couple of minutes, I can successfully connect to the bad host.

I attempted to Google this issue and found no related complaints, so I am wondering if I am unique, or this is something new to 15.04, or I am just going slightly crazy here.

Comment: This MIGHT be a DNS problem. I am using a local BIND9 server with localhost and 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. zones.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is not a local BIND9/named problem. I disabled my local named and the errors still happened. It has nothing to do with upstream DNS because my tablet on the same network works fine. It is a localized, specific network outage on this computer alone.

Comment: If other connections alre OK in the meantime, you effectvely ruled out layer 1-3 issues. Is it always the same host that your having problems with?

Comment: No, it randomly strikes any and every host I attempt to connect to. It's been GMail's outgoing mail server, forums.catholic.com, en.wikipedia.org, YouTube.com, divineoffice.org, all kinds of unrelated sites.

Comment: I am getting the same problem.  I installed the old `r8168-dkms` but nothing's changed.  I've also tried to set my DNS server specifically to Google DNS, but I don't know enough about Ubuntu at this point to know what's up with it.

Answer (score 3):

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 I have experienced similar problems of intermittent internet outages. I believe in my case this is an issue with the routing. The problem for me only happens when I am connected on the internet both through ethernet and through WiFi. The symptom is that I would occasionally lose internet connection for a few seconds. I clearly have a problem with the routing, as my WiFi connection shares priority with my ethernet connection for the addresses related to the DNS server. Check your DNS server address with:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

And your routing table with:

```
route -n
```

This issue seems related to a failure of network manager to set priority of ethernet over WiFi since the update to Ubuntu 15.04 and it is being described here:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1436330

I have installed network-manager_0.9.10.0-4ubuntu16_amd64.deb libnm-util2_0.9.10.0-4ubuntu16_amd64.deb but I believe the issue is still not thoroughly fixed yet.

Comment: I have not lost my Internet connection, and I have no complex routing situation or more than one interface.

Comment: This is my situation - test it by disabling wifi when connected to ethernet, everything should start working.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I have exactly the same problem after upgrading to 15.04 on my wired connection. When I pull out the eth-cable my wifi takes over and the network works perfect again, allthough a lot slower obviously.

My connection is like this: internet > ISP-router > repeater > my ubuntu 15.04 laptop (HP elitebook 8470w). 
My eth-card is an Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection.

Comment: I'm about to try this http://askubuntu.com/a/622230/87173

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/622230/87173 worked for my network card. It's about installing a different driver. Interestingly, Ethernet still worked for me on VirtualBox/Windows!

Comment: The problem still persists after installation of that driver mentioned. For the record, my Ethernet hardware is "00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)"

Comment: I'm sorry to report the problem has reappeared for me too. I need to check if a system upgrade has replaced the driver in question with a newer version.

Comment: Another suggestion: set the MTU size to 8192 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275361 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70761 (it doesn't work for me either, grrr)